# Grouping test results using Python coverage

Tags: python, django, nose, coverage.py, django-nose

I am testing a Django 1.6 application and I need some guidance using `django-nose` and `coverage`. Our Django app has the following structure:

```
manage.py
requirements.txt
/appname
    /apps
        /app1
        /app2
        /app3
```

Our top `appname` directory has an `apps` directory which contains all of our Django apps. When I test the full application I receive huge coverage output of every single package/module inside the individual apps. However, I would like to group the coverage results (statements, misses, coverage %) at the app level, not at the individual file level.

Can I do this?

Here are my relevant requirements:

```
coverage==3.6
django-nose==1.3
Django==1.6.10
nose==1.3.0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [Coverage API](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/api.html#api) to write your own custom coverage report.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Just points to the documentation. To vague, not helpful

Comment: @MarcusViniciusMelo: I don't think that's a fair assessment. The question is not clear enough to be answered more concretely than this. If you have any troubles using the Coverage API to achieve what you wanted to do, you should create a new question that details where you are stuck.